# Capture monomorphized generics in a macro

Tags: rust, macros, monomorphism

I have written a trait to serialize objects into iterators of little endian bytes:

```rust
pub trait ToLeBytes: Sized
where
    Self::Iter: Iterator<Item = u8>,
{
    type Iter;

    fn to_le_bytes(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}
```

I have implemented it for the primitive data types I need and also for `heapless::Vec`:

```rust
#[allow(clippy::cast_possible_truncation)]
#[cfg(feature = "heapless")]
impl<I, const SIZE: usize> ToLeBytes for heapless::Vec<I, SIZE>
where
    I: ToLeBytes,
    for<'a> <I as ToLeBytes>::Iter: Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a,
{
    type Iter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>>;

    fn to_le_bytes(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        let mut iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u8>> = Box::new(empty());

        if u8::try_from(SIZE).is_ok() {
            iterator = Box::new(<u8 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(self.len() as u8)));
        } else if u16::try_from(SIZE).is_ok() {
            iterator = Box::new(<u16 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(self.len() as u16)));
        } else if u32::try_from(SIZE).is_ok() {
            iterator = Box::new(<u32 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(self.len() as u32)));
        } else if u64::try_from(SIZE).is_ok() {
            iterator = Box::new(<u64 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(self.len() as u64)));
        }

        for item in self {
            iterator = Box::new(iterator.chain(<I as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(item)));
        }

        iterator
    }
}
```

However, since this code is intended to run on embedded systems with low performing hardware, I want to avoid heap allocations and thus want to get rid of the `Box`es.

Of course, chaining the iterators in basic rust is not possible, because each call to `.chain()` will return a new type of iterator.
Hence I thought that maybe a macro can do the trick, since I already did something similar for the [derive macro](https://github.com/PaulmannLighting/le-stream-derive/blob/main/src/to_le_bytes.rs) of that trait.

However, I of course do not want to implement the body for any possible `I` and `SIZE`, but only for those that are being used in the respective program.
Therefore, I'd need to run the macro on the monomorphized code.

I tried to google how to do this, but did not find any results.
How do I write a macro that is being passed in the monomorphized code of an `impl` block?
I don't want an entire solution, but a nudge into the right direction.

**Update**

I think that I'm almost there, thanks to Chayim's comments:

```rust
use crate::ToLeBytes;
use std::array::IntoIter;
use std::iter::FlatMap;
use std::slice::Iter;

pub struct ContainerIterator<'a, T, const HEADER_SIZE: usize>
where
    T: ToLeBytes,
{
    size_iterator: IntoIter<u8, HEADER_SIZE>,
    items_iterator: FlatMap<Iter<'a, T>, <T as ToLeBytes>::Iter, fn(&T) -> <T as ToLeBytes>::Iter>,
}

impl<'a, T, const HEADER_SIZE: usize> ContainerIterator<'a, T, HEADER_SIZE>
where
    T: ToLeBytes,
{
    fn from_size_iterator_and_slice(size_iterator: IntoIter<u8, HEADER_SIZE>, items: &[T]) -> Self
    where
        T: ToLeBytes,
    {
        Self {
            size_iterator,
            items_iterator: items
                .iter()
                .flat_map(|item| <T as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(item)),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T, const HEADER_SIZE: usize> Iterator for ContainerIterator<'a, T, HEADER_SIZE>
where
    T: ToLeBytes,
{
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(next_header) = self.size_iterator.next() {
            Some(next_header)
        } else {
            self.items_iterator.next()
        }
    }
}

pub enum SizedContainerIterator<'a, T>
where
    T: ToLeBytes,
{
    U8(ContainerIterator<'a, T, 1>),
    U16(ContainerIterator<'a, T, 2>),
    U32(ContainerIterator<'a, T, 4>),
    U64(ContainerIterator<'a, T, 8>),
}

impl<'a, T> SizedContainerIterator<'a, T>
where
    T: ToLeBytes,
{
    pub fn new(items: &[T], capacity: usize) -> SizedContainerIterator<'a, T>
    where
        T: ToLeBytes,
    {
        if u8::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            SizedContainerIterator::U8(ContainerIterator::from_size_iterator_and_slice(
                <u8 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(items.len() as u8)),
                items,
            ))
        } else if u16::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            SizedContainerIterator::U16(ContainerIterator::from_size_iterator_and_slice(
                <u16 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(items.len() as u16)),
                items,
            ))
        } else if u32::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            SizedContainerIterator::U32(ContainerIterator::from_size_iterator_and_slice(
                <u32 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(items.len() as u32)),
                items,
            ))
        } else if u64::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            SizedContainerIterator::U64(ContainerIterator::from_size_iterator_and_slice(
                <u64 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&(items.len() as u64)),
                items,
            ))
        } else {
            unreachable!("vec size exceeds u64");
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for SizedContainerIterator<'a, T>
where
    T: ToLeBytes,
{
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self {
            Self::U8(iterator) => iterator.next(),
            Self::U16(iterator) => iterator.next(),
            Self::U32(iterator) => iterator.next(),
            Self::U64(iterator) => iterator.next(),
        }
    }
}
```

However, now I have the issue of specifying the lifetime for the `Iter` type:

```rust
#[allow(clippy::cast_possible_truncation)]
#[cfg(feature = "heapless")]
impl<I, const SIZE: usize> ToLeBytes for heapless::Vec<I, SIZE>
where
    I: ToLeBytes,
    for<'a> <I as ToLeBytes>::Iter: Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a,
{
    type Iter = SizedContainerIterator<'_, I>;

    fn to_le_bytes(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        SizedContainerIterator::new(self, SIZE)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a custom iterator type and avoid `chain()`.

Comment: Or just use `flat_map()`.

Comment: `flat_map()` works for the elements of the `heapless::Vec`. However, I need to prepend the  size, the type of which is only determined during monomorpization (see the if/else). But I'll try a custom iterator approach.

Comment: For that you can use `chain()` with an enum. Or a manual iterator, as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I now just need to figure out, how to specify the iterator's lifetime (updated question).

Comment: You need to make the associated type a GAT on `&self`'s lifetime. Or, alternatively, take `self` and impl the trait for `&'a heapless::Vec`. But if you use an enum and `flat_map()`, you don't need a custom iterator, `chain()` will be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chayim's hints, I got it working:

```rust
#![cfg(feature = "heapless")]
use crate::ToLeBytes;
use std::array::IntoIter;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum SizePrefixIterator {
    U8(IntoIter<u8, 1>),
    U16(IntoIter<u8, 2>),
    U32(IntoIter<u8, 4>),
    U64(IntoIter<u8, 8>),
}

impl SizePrefixIterator {
    #[allow(clippy::cast_possible_truncation)]
    pub fn new(len: usize, capacity: usize) -> Self {
        if u8::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            Self::U8(<u8 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(len as u8))
        } else if u16::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            Self::U16(<u16 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(len as u16))
        } else if u32::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            Self::U32(<u32 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(len as u32))
        } else if u64::try_from(capacity).is_ok() {
            Self::U64(<u64 as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(len as u64))
        } else {
            unreachable!("container size exceeds u64");
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SizePrefixIterator {
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self {
            Self::U8(header) => header.next(),
            Self::U16(header) => header.next(),
            Self::U32(header) => header.next(),
            Self::U64(header) => header.next(),
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "heapless")]
impl<T, const SIZE: usize> ToLeBytes for heapless::Vec<T, SIZE>
where
    T: Sized + ToLeBytes,
{
    type Iter = std::iter::Chain<
        size_prefix_iterator::SizePrefixIterator,
        FlatMap<
            <Self as IntoIterator>::IntoIter,
            <T as ToLeBytes>::Iter,
            fn(T) -> <T as ToLeBytes>::Iter,
        >,
    >;

    fn to_le_bytes(self) -> Self::Iter {
        size_prefix_iterator::SizePrefixIterator::new(self.len(), SIZE).chain(
            self.into_iter()
                .flat_map(<T as ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes as fn(T) -> <T as ToLeBytes>::Iter),
        )
    }
}
```